# Select differing number of top X records for each group

Tags: loops, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table of customers who each have an associated p-value, as well as a group id. I need to select the top X customers for each group id, where X differs for each group id. I'd then like to put those selected customers into a single table.

For instance, I have a table of group id's and top customer count called `count_table`:

| group_id | cust_count |
| --- | --- |
| A123 | 78 |
| B456 | 90 |

And then a table of customers, their group ids, and p-values called `customer_table`.

| group_id | customer_id | p_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A123 | 1001 | 0.05 |
| B456 | 1002 | 0.06 |

My desired output would look identical to the customer table above, but would only include the top X customers I've identified in each group. For this I've created an empty temporary table with matching columns called `results_table`.

I'm still fairly new to BigQuery, so my Python background makes me want to use a for-loop to achieve this. But I'm not sure how to insert the results for each group into my temporary results table. This is what I've written so far:

```
create temp table results_table
(group_id string, customer_id string, p_value float64);

for record in (select * from count_table) 
do
(
 select group_id, customer_id, p_value from 
  (select *, row_number() over (order by p_value) as rownum from customer_table
   where group_id = record.group_id)
 where rownum <= record.cust_count
);
end for;
```

Adding `insert into results_table` just after the `do` line doesn't work, so is there a better way to achieve this? Is there a way to avoid using a loop entirely? Thanks

Comment: Hi there, It is not really clear how the cust_count value in count_table is 78 given customer_table has 1 row associated, are you able to give better representation of input and output table please?

Comment: @BihagKashikar I just gave a couple example records. In reality the customer_table has thousands of records. The count_table has less than 5.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution (or at least the one I came up with) is fairly straightforward. I partitioned `row_number()` by group_id, left-joined the `customer_table` with the `count_table`, and then selected only the records where `rownum <= cust_count`:

```
select A.group_id, customer_id, p_value from
(select *, row_number() over (partition by group_id order by p_value) as rownum 
 from customer_table) A
left join count_table B
on A.group_id = B.group_id
where A.rownum <= B.cust_count
```